# Xubuntu: disable system sounds

Tags: sound, xubuntu

Since upgrading to Xubuntu 18, the system started playing sounds (beeping).

How do I disable this?

I've tried disabling beeping in X server - nothing changed

```
xset -b
xset b off
```

I've looked into `amixer`, but it says that the system sounds channel is muted.

The kernel module `pcspkr` is not loaded.

I put `set bell-style none` in `/etc/inputrc` and `gtk-error-bell = 0` in `~/.gtkrc-2.0` (I don't really know how to figure out what GTK version it should be and whether that's important for config file.  I can see this system having some packages with `gtk2` and `gtk3` in the name).

Finally, I looked into: `Settings > Appearance > Enable Sound Events`, but the checkbox isn't ticked.

I'm out of ideas...  I'm not allowed to open the case: it's a company's computer, and working like this is not really possible.